# turn off hashicorp vault server dev

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am messing around with and testing Hashicorp Vault. I am starting a vault server in dev mode within the mac terminal:

```
vault server -dev
```

Accordingly, I get some data if I do

```
vault status
```

However, if I want to turn the server off and start it again, I have to restart the computer. Closing the mac shell will not do the trick, as I assume that the server continues to live in the mac memory. I have googled a lot to see if there is a simple command to stop the dev server but found none.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> the proccess, vault will terminate and you will lose all the data you stored in there. No need to restart the computer.

If that doesn’t work, you can kill it with `pkill -9 vault`

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to as this hashicorp vault official link: [Deploy Vault#Clean up](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-deploy#clean-up)

it describes 2 methods:

1. `ctrl` + `c`
2. `pgrep -f vault | xargs kill`

this is the description in official documentation:

> Before continuing on to the Using the HTTP APIs with Authentication tutorial, press Ctrl+C to stop the server.
> Or, kill the Vault process from a command.
>
> ```
> pgrep -f vault | xargs kill
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to as this hashicorp vault official link: [Deploy Vault#Clean up](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-deploy#clean-up)

it describes 2 methods:

1. use `ctrl` + `c` to stop the server.
2. or use `pgrep -f vault | xargs kill` command to kill vault process.

this is the description of official documentation:

> press `Ctrl+C` to stop the server.
>
> Or, kill the Vault process from a command.
> `pgrep -f vault | xargs kill`